# What is the equivalent of keccak256 in solidity?

Tags: solidity, web3js, ethers.js

I am going to get the same value that is produced by keccak256 in solidity.

This is the code in my solidity file and I want to get the same value in the javascript file using `ethers` or `web3`.

```
bytes32 node = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(nodeString));
```

I got the same value of `abi.encodePacked(nodeString))` by using `ethers.utils.solidityPack`.

```
const abiEncodedPackedString = ethers.utils.solidityPack(['string'], [nodeString]);
```

But when I tried `ethers.utils.solidityKeccak256`, the result wasn't the same as `node` in solidity.

```
const nodeInJavascript = ethers.utils.solidityKeccak256(['string], [abiEncodePackedString]);
```

I have also tried `ethers.utils.keccak256(abiEncodePackedString)` but I couldn't get the result either.

Answer (score 0):

in web3 I used this and worked:

```
export const createCourseHash = (courseId, account) => {
  const hexCourseId = web3.utils.utf8ToHex(courseId)
  const courseHash = web3.utils.soliditySha3(
    { type: "bytes16", value: hexCourseId },
    { type: "address", value: account }
  )
  return courseHash
}
```

in ethers, you are passing plain string. try to convert it to `hex` value. in fact if you check the [documentation](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/utils/hashing/), they are not passing plain strings:

> The value MUST be data, such as:
>
> - an Array of numbers
> - a data hex string (e.g. "0x1234")
> - a Uint8Array

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Do you use `keccak256` in the solidity file, in that case?

Comment: Hi, Yilmz. Could you explain your answer in more detail, please?